# can i again reinstall java on ubuntu?because both windows and ubuntu is in my system and java is configured on windows?

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat

iam new to ubuntu. i have been working on windows. My question is can we run web application developed in windows on ubuntu? both windows and ubuntu is installed in my system java is congigured on windows. Shall i again re instal java  mysql and tomcat on ubuntu? please help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

While Java is made such that a Java application can run across different operating systems without changing the code and recompiling it. It is (for example) somewhat easy to introduce Windows specific things and thus preventing it to run on Linux or Mac.

Of course you will need to install everything that your java application needs again on the Linux side. Alternatively you could also setup a MySql-Server on a different computer and make it accessible from both Windows and Linux side.